# What is difference between Account Vs Service SAS in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am new to Azure and learning the technologies in Azure.

Storage Account Authentications:-
Storage Access Keys
Shared Access Signature (SAS)

In SAS, I see there are 2 types for SAS such as Account and Service SAS.

I have generated SAS token in Azure Portal. Refer here [image]

How can I use SAS token, Blob service SAS URL, File service SAS URL, Table service SAS URL, Queue service SAS URL ?

I am not able to understand where I can find or how do I generate or use Account and Service SAS by above screen shot.

Kindly provide me example to understand it.

Comment: You should start by reading up on Azure Storage Shared Access Signatures (there is quite a bit of documentation about them). Then come back and ask specific programming questions about them. Your question is essentially asking for tutorial / documentation links, which is an off-topic question (and honestly, if you do a google search, you'll find everything you need to gain an understanding).

Comment: I would suggest you read the difference between an Account & Service SAS here first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/delegating-access-with-a-shared-access-signature. Then please update your question with any clarification questions that you may have.

Comment: I assumed that you could refer to the "Data Plane Security" section in this  [tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/storage/storage-security-guide.md) about storage to have a better understanding of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure storage accounts come in two flavors: standard accounts, which provide access to Azure Storage services such as tables, queues, files, blobs, and disks; and blob storage accounts, which are optimized for blob storage. But whichever account type you choose, a master key is used to grant administrative access.

But if you want to grant limited or temporary access, giving away your storage account key isn’t the best idea. To solve this problem, Azure uses Shared Access Signatures (SAS) for safely delegating access to objects in storage. A Shared Access Signature is a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) that includes all the information about the resources to which you want to grant access, and relevant permissions in the form of a token.

More SAS Use Cases please refer to this [link](https://www.petri.com/microsoft-azure-understanding-shared-access-signatures-sas).

@Gaurav Mantri said, you also could learn from the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/delegating-access-with-a-shared-access-signature).

You could get SAS from Azure Portal.

[image]

Update:

Beginning with version 2015-04-05, Azure Storage supports two types of shared access signatures (SAS):

A service-level SAS, described in this topic. The service SAS delegates access to a resource in just one of the storage services: the Blob, Queue, Table, or File service.

An account-level SAS, introduced with version 2015-04-05. The account SAS delegates access to resources in one or more of the storage services. All of the operations available via a service SAS are also available via an account SAS.

More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/constructing-a-service-sas).

@Karan

For an Account level SAS click all the allowed services & resource types. It is up to you decide what permissions they have and when you want the SAS to work and expire.

To create a Service Level SAS you would just deselect the Allowed Services you don’t want. For instance if I wanted to create a Blob Service SAS I would just select Blob..

To understand the diff by the using the token you have generated, simply try accessing/updating something which you have NOT allowed in your SAS token [allow everything (Account SAS) vs allow only one (Service SAS) service &resource]

Comment: I have generated SAS like as yours mentioned in screenshot. But what is the Account and Service SAS from the SAS token, Blob, File, Queue, Table Service SAS URLs ?

Comment: The service SAS delegates access to a resource in just one of the storage services: the Blob, Queue, Table, or File service.   The account SAS delegates access to resources in one or more of the storage services. All of the operations available via a service SAS are also available via an account SAS.

Comment: I understand the theory of Account Vs Service SAS. How do I use it by using the token which I generated to understand difference between them.

Comment: I have same confusing when I read Azure SAS document today about how to distinguish Account Level SAS and Service level SAS. I think this is a valid question, and the answer provided here is actually wrong.

My understanding is you can only create Account SAS from Azure portal -> Storage account -> SAS, it's still a account SAS even if you only select one blob service.

Comment: You can use "az storage container generate-sas" to create service SAS and "az storage account generate-sas" to create account SAS, Account SAS looks like "se=2020-06-01&sp=r&sv=2018-03-28&ss=b", service SAS doesn't have "ss=b"

Comment: Also "az storage container generate-sas" support --policy-name, account SAS doesn't.